# Curl con certificado pem problema

Tags: curl, certificado

Mi problema es que estoy intentando acceder a un servidor con curl y un certificado de seguridad y no me deja. El codigo que pongo en la terminal de ubuntu es:

curl https://ipservidor:puerto --cacert archivo.pem

El resultado que obtengo es:

curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: archivo.pem
  CApath: none

¿Podrían ayudarme a resolverlo?
Gracias

Comment: ¿Tú archivo archivo.pem tiene permisos lectura/ejecución? Date una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para ver como mejorar tus preguntas y tener mayor posibilidad de respuesta.

Comment: Si si los tiene

Comment: Tal vez necesites instalar un paquete o dependencia. Mira: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160909/how-do-i-deal-with-certificates-using-curl-while-trying-to-access-an-https-url